# Implementing informatica logic in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

How can we implement a below logic in spark ?

If a column value is null then it should return ' '
If ltrim(rtrim(column)) is null then it should return ' '
Else it should populate the value of that column

Comment: I think you mean, scala, pyspark or java

Comment: @thebluephantom pyspark

Comment: handy to know that... but I am a SCALA person. if you google you should find such an answer elsewhere

Comment: RDD or dataframe or RDS?

Comment: 'a '  returns 'a' I presume

Comment: @thebluephantom I need help in deciding which is the best choice ?rdd or DF considering performance. As per my knowledge DF is the best .

Comment: well both are parallel processing so I am not sure totally an issue, but it is stated that DS's are better but I suggest you look at this, for example, https://data-flair.training/blogs/apache-spark-rdd-vs-dataframe-vs-dataset/

Comment: @thebluephantom cool stuff..but I'm novice to this. How can I implement the above logic ? Can any one help pls

Comment: novices get better by reading and doing, get a databricks account

Comment: Tell me what you think of the answer

Answer (score 1):

`df=df.withColumn("new_col",when(col("old_col").isNull(),"").otherwise(col("old_col")))`

prefer DF over rdd as it involves under the hood optimizations

https://databricks.com/blog/2016/07/14/a-tale-of-three-apache-spark-apis-rdds-dataframes-and-datasets.html

Answer (score 0):

I am not a pyspark person, but if you look at the examples here below in Scala and

1. look at the pyspark lambda approach and lack of val if I remember correctly
2. and write your own def as you would do a reusable transformation in Informatica

then you should be able to move forward. I provide a couple of ways of trimming and if else with map in RDD.

3 lines to show the general principles:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(List((" aaa", "x"), ("bbbb ", "y"), (" cc ", "z"), ("gggg  ", " a"), ("    ", "b")))
val rdd2 = rdd.map{ case (field1, field2) => ( field1.replaceAll(" ", ""), field1.trim, field1, field2) }
val rdd3 = rdd2.map{ case (field1, field2, field3, field4) => (field1.replaceAll(" ", ""), if (field1.trim == "") " "  else field1 , field3, field4) }
```